# Double free errors when using shallow copies of objects... how to fix?

Tags: c++, object, copy, delete-operator

How do I remove double (delete) errors from shallow copied object vs original object.

A simple example:

```
class INT
{
   int *p; //dynamic.

   //define here fancy constructors etc.
   set(int i){ p=new int; p=i;}
   ~INT();
}

INT::~INT()
{
   if(p) delete p;
}

void somefunction(INT a)
{
   //done some stuff ,e.g. call some display function
}
//note here, that a destructor will be called, and a.p will vanish.

int main(void)
{
   INT a; a.set(2);
   somefunction(a);//shallow copy
}
//CRASH BOOM BOOM!
```

I would like a generic solution, because passing objects is a trivial thing, and something as naive as this, resulting into a horrific/terrific error is just 'awesome'.

I suspect there are many ways around this (some of which even I can think of), but I was curious if there is any generic (applicable almost everywhere) way of solving this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: note: I do not want to use references , or is using references the generic solution ?

Comment: @nik: First off, I don't see where someone said anything about references. That said, if they did, why wouldn't you use them? They're a critical language feature (required for copy-constructors, in fact), and avoiding them is silly. You need to write a copy-constructor and assignment-operator (that's what the rule of three Q&A talks about), and the best way to do that is with the copy-and-swap idiom (which the copy-and-swap Q&A talks about). (Or you may disable copying and assignment altogether, as the rule of three Q&A mentions). Or simply avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: ok, so for a huge dynamic resource it seems following is better way: 1. Disable copy and = operators 2. use references in functions that make use of object (to avoid pass by value, or shallow copy)

Comment: @nik: Yes. In general, pass everything by reference unless it's a built-in type, or unless you need a copy for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all objects with dynamic members, it is usually best to define your own copy and copy-assignment operations for just this reason.

Regarding 'big' objects and expensive copying, [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is a technique employed by many languages and patterns to circumvent this problem of pointer ownership. Note that all copies of an object point to the same shared object in this case, so a modification of the shared object from one instance will be visible to others. See the [boost shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you have apointer object inside your class then you need to declare your own copy constructor and assignment operator method to avoid shallow copy problem.
Look ate this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) for mor info on this

Comment: No the problem is, in this case the object is just a simple int, in other cases it might be something far to expensive to copy.

Comment: @nik: "Big" is a vague word. Again, what measurements? You can't just assume you need to make some optimization, it's a waste of time. Your concern should be learning to program in the most correct way possible. When you're *finished* you may profile your application and get real data that tells you where the slow spots are. Guessing is not data.

Comment: @nikhilelite if you really want to avoid copying, you should investigate using shared_ptr<> instead of a raw C/C++ pointer.  That will make your code simpler and greatly improve the chances of it working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this!
Doctor: Don't do that.

Chances are at least 100:1 that you can write your code just fine without dealing with a raw pointer. Depending on the situation, you may need a smart pointer or you may need a collection, but the chances that you need a pointer seem quite remote.

Instead of asking about how to fix what you're doing, you'd be much better off telling us what you're trying to accomplish, so we can tell you about how to do that.

Comment: Any tips on a conclusive article on these kind of issues.

Comment: You haven't really told us what the issue *is* yet. If you want to avoid deep copies, you might want to look into something like Boost's smart pointers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Answer (score 1):

The question "How do I avoid double delete from shallow copied objects?" should really be "How do I avoid shallow copies, when I don't want that?".

Some options are:
- avoid raw pointers to allocated memory
- don't copy the objects!  :-)
- manage the memory outside of the objects
- use a smart pointer
- implement deep copying

Your choice depends on what you are actually using your objects for.