# Destructor of function argument called

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Here's what I had:

```
// define structures A & B...
// Brief example of the functions:
struct B* foo(const struct A mystruct)
{
    struct B *outstruct = new S();
    // Copying values from structure A to B
    return(outstruct);
}
int main()
{
    struct A *mystruct = new A();
    struct B *tmp = foo(*mystruct);
    delete(A); delete(B);
    return 0;
}
```

I kept getting a core dump message, so I put a printf statement in the destructor of A. It showed that the destructor was called twice: (1) at the end of main, as expected, and (2) at the end of foo.

So, I changed the foo function to pass mystruct as a pointer (making the necessary syntax changes) and the destructor was called only once, at the end of main as desired. What is the reason for this? Or might I be missing something else?

Comment: Your argument has a non-reference type, so it is pass-by-value, and a copy will be made.  Then the copy will be destroyed, using the destructor.

Comment: BTW, it seems you are writing Java code in C++.  Try to break that habit.  Good C++ code rarely uses the `new` operator.  Just use local non-pointers variables in most cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and also of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268342/c-double-free-errors-when-using-shallow-copies-of-objects-how-to-fix

Comment: @BenVoigt Just an example. I need to create it the structure on the stack for my actual application.

Comment: If you're starting out with C++ you will learn, live and love RAII.

Comment: I think you copied `struct *B foo(const struct A mystruct)` incorrectly as it's not valid C++ proably you meant `struct B* foo(const struct A mystruct)` or as is more typically seen just `B *foo(const A mystruct)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `struct B* foo(const struct A mystruct)` passes `A` by value. So `mystruct` in the function is a copy of the one in `main`. The destructor therefore is called on it when the program flow leaves the function.

If instead you pass:

- by pointer: `B *foo(const A *mystruct)`
  or
- by reference: `B *foo(const A &mystruct)`

Then no copy is made of an `A` so there is no destructor call for an `A` on leaving the function.

If `A` were implemented correctly then the pass by value version should not core-dump. Though to understand why it core-dumps we'd need to see more of the code.

Comment: As someone who uses Matlab 80% of the time, silly me :). That's why it worked when I used a pointer. Thanks!

Comment: @KEH As R Sahu points out something is wrong in `A` to cause the pass by value version to core dump.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `foo`, a temporary object is constructed from `*mystruct` by calling the copy constructor. The temporary object is destructed when you return from `foo`. The core dump is caused by mismanaged memory in `A`.